MaterialTextInputLayout, when i have end_icon mode clear_text clears drawables
I have a MaterialTextInputLayout which has an end_icon_mode="clear_text", when i use startIconDrawable for MaterialTextInputLayout, it has a big padding between edittext and icon, so i decided to use drawableStart for TextInputEditText, but when I start typing, it shows clearButton, but removes drawableStart of TextInputEditText. I have to prevent removing drawableStart of I need to set custom padding to MaterialTextInputLayout startIconDrawable
I searched forums in github and other places, but didn't find any information about this problem

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
